# Definition vs presence of variables

Tags: c, computer-science

I'm in an introductory programming class and our professor has really rushed through the section on variables. A lot of the information I've read in the textbook and on this website has been difficult to understand with how little I know. Here's one of the sample code fragments he gave us:

```
    void
    printHi(char *name)
        {
        int count = 3;
        printf("Hi There, %s-%d\n",name,count);
        return;
        }
```

We need to be able to identify from a fragment which variables are defined and which are just present. My understanding, based on what I know, is that the integer *count* is both present and defined while the string *name* is only present, not defined. Is that correct, or am I missing the mark here?

I really hate to ask this with so many questions with the same title on here, but even after reading through the others I'm still not completely sure. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid the terminology is not universal, and you really need to refer to the definitions your prof gave you.

Comment: Somtimes people speak of *occurrence* of a variable. BTW, you could view `printf` as some "variable" also ... Read wikipage on [λ-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) and on [variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: Read also about [free vs bound variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)

Comment: Teachers not using standard terminology are bad teachers.

Comment: @pablo1977 - Except that much of the "standard" terminology is pure bunk.

Answer (score 1):

`char *name` is called a paramenter. It is passed into the function called `printHi`. Just like in math when you say f(x) = 2x + 3, x is a paramenter.

`int count = 3;` is the next variable which is called a local variable because it is defined in the function and when the function returns the variable is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

"present" is not standard terminology. `name` is defined by `char *name` in the parameter list.

Every variable is defined somewhere. It's hard to know what he means by "present", but if he means "was used in this code" then you could say that `name` and `count` are both defined and present.

Comment: I have a bad feeling that he might say "name is not defined here because it was defined in the calling function", or something, which is just wrong. It's hard to know what to do when professors make their own stuff up.

Answer (score 0):

name is actually defined in the printHi() function,
when the other function called the printHi() function, it passed the VALUE of the string to printHi(), and that is received and stored in the name variable. To store the received string printHi() function makes a string named 'name' and store3s it.